# how to create link to different website in mvc

Tags: html, hyperlink

I want to create link to www.google.com with use < a href = "www.google.com >link to google< /a >.
But I aready get link http://mysite/www.google.com
Anyone can help me????

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">link to google</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with MVC. When linking externally, you must include the full url, including the protocol.

http://www.google.com for example.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't you just prefix the href with "http://" ?

Comment: And also fix his attribute value quoting.